# How to send a message on a socket when no listen?

Tags: c, linux, sockets

Message queues can send messages even when the other side is not present to read it, the other side can come slowly later and read the accumulated queue.

How do I achieve that in socket? everytime i write to a socket when there is no one to listen(and bind ofcourse) it fails [connecting stream socket: Connection refused or connecting stream socket: No such file or directory ]

Atfirst, Iam looking at only AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM

Thx
Nathan

Comment: There is no concept in OSI Transport Layer networking that will give you what you want. It has to be implemented at a higher level in the network layer, just as you mentioned with a message queuing library.

Comment: You changed your question to only cover Unix domain sockets, so I assume you are doing `IPC`. I suggest looking at Sys V IPC queues since they are universally available on *nix systems.

Comment: +1 thx, I already have the message queue implementation of my API, but people are not happy with msgq becuase surprisingly, the max msgq are only in hundreds, local sockets can scale better so i am investigating on those lines.

Comment: Thos parameters are adjustable by tuning the operating system generally. But yes, Sys V IPC is generally provided only to meet the requirements of the interface and are not concerned with scalability.

Comment: @EricUrban, OSI is just a figment in some overheated imaginations. Its Transport Layer has nothing whatsoever in common with real-world networks.

Comment: @vonbrand Yes, OSI is a concept of course. But the actual implementations, i.e. TCP, UDP, SCTP, etc are not. Either way he updated his question to indicate he is doing Unix sockets only.

Comment: @EricUrban, OSI is an unfinished (!) standard, which is just based on a completely different network model than the one in everyday use. Yes, its lower levels (0 to 1 or perhaps 1.5 or so) are useful (that's why communications people talk about OSI all day long), the other levels have nothing to do with reality. TCP/IP is _totally_ different. All the "equivalences" in networking books and so are total nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

Can't be done. If there is nobody to accept data, there is nobody to accept data.

Look at how [systemd](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd) (in Linux) handles this, perhaps it solves your problem?